# openvpn: restrict client communications

Tags: firewall, openvpn

I have 4 windows servers (2008 and 2019) that are correctly connected to a OpenVPN server (ubuntu), and communicating like a charm thanks to “client-to-client” option, I can ping, RDP, access Apache ...
All the clients have a ccd file for static ips.
I would like to allow only one client to access these servers for administration purpose and prevent them from seeing each other.
I can’t find a simple solution to this, please help.

Comment: in an ad you can restrict the access. and there are a hell more possibilities. what did you tried?

Comment: I wanted to do this in the vpn server side for scalability